# есть код, который должен выдать путь

Tags: c#

```
String sndc = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "SDPClient.exe");
Console.WriteLine(sndc);
```

Этот код должен выдавать путь к файлу, который программа будет искать на разных пк в зависимости от того где запустили.
Но он выдает: `C:\Users\Василевский НА\source\repos\SDP Diagnostics\SDP Diagnostics\bin\Debug\SDPClient.exe`
На скрине видно какой файл мне нужен, подскажите почему не работает?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, вы соединяете по факту каталог запуска приложения и имя файла, в результате получаете соединенное то, что соединили, все логично. Каком образом `GetCurrentDirectory` должен превратиться в Program Files?

Comment: _Кажется я не верно все объяснил, у меня есть информация, что на компьютере есть файл SDP 3.0.exe и мне нужно чтобы моя программа нашла его и выдала путь( он может в любой папке и диске) это возможно?_ - да, в данном случае вопрос закрыт как дубликат, ссылка на ответ вверху.

Comment: Если Вы ищете директорию с установленной программой, то почему не прочитать путь к этой директории из регистра? Отсюда HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall или HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. Тем более, если Вы знаете имя программы или её GUID...